# Left toolbar is missing - Blender 2.81a osx

Tags: interface, osx

[image: Closed toolbar]
[image: Opened toolbar]

I don't know what is happening. My left toolbar is missing.
It is closed toolbar:
It is opened toolbar (shortcut **T**)
How I can fix it?

Comment: There is a small arrow on the left. Drag that to the right.

Comment: Didn't help. Just increased the empty space :(